# xcode storyboard reverting in compile

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I started having some very odd behaviour in Xcode 4.5 recently. I made a change to a `UITableViewController` with static cells but the changes did not appear in the simulator and neither did my code changes. I removed the app from the simulator and ran clean on the project, then started again and all the changes appeared. I made another code change, ran the debugger via simulator and once again I saw my old `UITableViewController` values and my code changes were absent. This project is using storyboards, but I am not sure if this problem is related to just storyboards given my code changes are reverted as well.

I am deeply confused here. Not even clean fixed this issue.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my simulator got all messed up. After resetting the content and settings, it is all working properly again. Very odd.